Proof about multiplying another submatrix while calculating the determinant
I took a linear algebra class. However, while lecturing on inverse matrix, the professor said that the following content is trivial, so We skipped over the proof. However, I was so curious about the proof method for this content that I posted this question.
$$\begin{vmatrix} a & b & c\\d & e & f\\g & h & i \end{vmatrix}=$$
$$dC_{11}-eC_{12}+fC_{13}=0$$
$$d(ei - fh) - e(di - fg) + f(dh - eg) =0$$
In other words, in the process of calculating the determinant, it is a process of multiplying a submatrix other than the original submatrix to be multiplied. It is said that multiplying like this always results in 0, which is easy to understand in the case of 3 by 3 matrix, but I am not sure how to prove it by expanding it to the general case.

See Other proof for the Second Laplace theorem? for example.
